# Why can't i use static css files?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm currently creating django project in pycharm, I was trying to use bootstrap example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/blog/ but it refused to work.
I created static directory inside my app and put the css files needed for the example to work.

I used {% static %} to reference the css files in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogs/bootstrap.min.css' %}" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="{% static 'blogs/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but the output was https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyoNz.jpg instead of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/blog/

However when i put the direct links to the css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/blog/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it worked just well.
The css files were properly detected by django when i used the static method:

```
[11/Jan/2020 16:16:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13290
[11/Jan/2020 16:16:33] "GET /static/blogs/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 159521
[11/Jan/2020 16:16:33] "GET /static/blogs/blog.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1781
[11/Jan/2020 16:16:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13290
[11/Jan/2020 16:22:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13365
```

Comment: Did you configured `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your setting.py properly?

Comment: Are you sure that your static file is identical to that from the web? The size does not seem to match...

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it seems you did 2 mistakes.

1.to load static in a template its better you use {% load static %}

2.it seems you forgot to configure your static folder in the settings.py file of your project by using `STATIC_ROOT`